# south: how to ignore a changed model while creating a migration for an app

Tags: python, django, django-south

I have two changed models in an app, but i want to create a migration for only one model while ignoring the other, is this possible using a variation of the

```
./manage.py schemamigration app --auto
```

command?

Comment: Why not undo the changes to one model, run `schemamigration --auto`, then reapply the changes to the undone model and run `schemamigration --auto` again to get your two migrations?

Comment: are you using git? mVChr's solution would be easy with git (or any other version control system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to create migration. But I will only defined two ways.

```
 //migrate the changes of all models of the app
 ./manage.py schemamigration app --auto

 //migrate only the changes of the given model or 1 model
 python manage.py schemamigration app_name extend_modelname --auto
```